# How does this prototyping style work?

Tags: pcb, soldering, prototyping, copper

I'm a little puzzled about a prototyping style I've seen used recently. Here is an example picture of a circuit made in this way:
[image]

Can someone explain the process of making a board like this? Why are the copper traces covered with solder? How are the components connected together and how do they reach an electrical ground?

Comment: Where did you find it, Nico?

Comment: http://72.52.208.92/~gbpprorg/mil/gps5/index.html almost all of the circuits are constructed using a similar technique.

Comment: "Why are the copper traces covered with solder?" I think it is silver not solder! for high frequency, the enginer use of silver(and also in many cases gold) for this reason: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

Comment: Would you mind providing a link to some more information on how this is done?

Comment: For gold plating? Do you want to do gold plate?

Comment: Like how is that done in practice (with silver)? A conductive paste or something? And could that be solder? Just curious because it is mentioned as soldering throughout the description.

Comment: I'd expect the copper to be tinned (coated with solder) rather than silver plated.  Tinning will prevent the copper from tarninshing, so it will remain easily solderable.  The copper area along the bottom edge may be the circuit ground.  The two larger copper areas at the top edge may also be ground.  The components are connected by the metal strips and areas on the board.

Comment: Judging the various tracks that look like stubs (perpendicular traces that appear to go nowhere), I think it is an RF board. All dimensions (lengths, widths, distances, angles) will be extremely accurate. It is not just another prototyping style. Silver plating is not uncommon. On the other hand, it does look like it has been hand drawn with a PCB pen and subsequently etched.

Comment: Ground is probably the majority of the underside of the board; you can see the vias done with bits of wire poked through and soldered top (and presumably bottom).  Large volumes of solder on tracks may be for current-carrying, or it might just be tinning to make it easier to solder.  I agree that it looks like an RF board; I doubt it was hand-drawn, it was probably done with a board router.

Comment: Alright so I'm still not clear, let's say he/she etched this board, now it has the copper traces exposed. How does one apply solder efficiently in the thin layer seen in the picture on all the copper areas? Is there some sort of tool that does this? I'm going to assume that is solder and not conductive silver because silver is mentioned nowhere in the description whereas solder is and there are pictures of a spool.

Comment: One way of obtaining a relatively even, thin layer of solder on the copper is to use a hot air soldering gun. The solder used can either be flux-core, or pure solder plus added flux.

Comment: This just a homemade PCB board, which as been tinned (http://youtu.be/WAAdBIsvacs). The big blobs of solder you see are just the via to the opposite side of the PCB: the ground. They are covered in tin and solder to make a good connection. It is required to have as much via as possible to get a solid ground.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously a hand drawn circuit board. Look at the isolated runners in the top right of the photo. They seem to be areas drawn to allow other circuitry to be added later.

As for the coating, it is silver plating. Many chemical products are available to inexpensively add a silver coating ( http://www.ehow.com/how_7943385_diy-silver-brush-plating.html ) .  Notice the very even and smooth plating even on the un-used "runners".

> Can someone explain the process of making a board like this?

Boards like this start with a board already coated with copper, and then the copper is etched away using Ferric Cloride.  Typically one uses a coating (sometimes applied by pen) that will keep the Ferric Cloride away from the copper (you can even use finger-nail polish) . Only bare (not covered by a resist or pen coating) copper will be disolved (eaten away). The remaining copper is what had been covered by the coating (pen resist) before the "etching" process.

The silver plating is often used for RF (radio frequency) properties. But more commonly used as an anti-corrosive (keeps copper from turning green or oxidizing). The silver will tarnish, but the copper remains easily solderable.

What is on the opposite side of the board is unknowable from the photo supplied. The original designer may have had ground circuits or ground plane on the other side.

Advantage of this type of circuit board includes being very inexpensive, and rapidly made, in single quantity.

Tin/lead solder applies very well to silver coated copper traces.